# Can I index RDB with lucene?

Tags: java, jdbc, lucene, relational-database

I have a RDB and I index it. But the fields in de database that are related, in the lucene index aren't. So how can I index this relation? And, of course, then can I search it well?

I search in google but I only find that I have, without the relation, I think should be something for this, but I didn't find

Thanks for response! :)

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you can do in lucene is store the ID from your relational db against each index record. You need to place an amount of data in lucene from your relational store. You then fire a search off against lucene which gives you the ID or IDs of the relational records that have matched the search and you could then use that to retreive the data from your relational store.

Here's a presentation on the subject: http://www.slideshare.net/frankmashraqi/lucene-and-mysql

Comment: I found LuSql, it does the relation I was looking for, but not index like my application, I am trying to understand the LuSql code for implement my own relational indexation. If I discover how do it, I say here. Does someone have that I am trying to do?